# Why do I get different results from profiler in Visual Studio 2010 RC

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow, profile

I have setup 1 project in VS2010 RC. A workflow console application that simply counts from 1 to 10000 and writes each number to console.
When I execute "F5" this application it takes minutes to finish, but when i execute this application with profiling it finishes in 3-5 seconds.
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Found why,
Because of the VS2010 debugger.
When I build the application or launch without debugging it finishes in 3 seconds.